# Controlling multiple children, handling sigchld

Tags: c, unix, signals, wait

Let's say i have a main C program that has to wait for `sigchld` of two children, and that these two sons have to do two separate task, for example one should write "1", and the other 
one should write "2" ,wait 2 seconds and then terminate, now how should I write the code so that the father write his children's pid only after the two sons ends with sigchld? It's obvious that i'm missing some theory, if you look at my code you will understand what my issue is.

After that i'll have to force the execution of the second son before the first son, suggestion?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pids[2], cpid, i, status;
    char buff[200];

    for(i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) 
            perror("errno");
        else
        {
            //child
            if (pids[i] == 0)
            {       
                if(i == 0)
                    write(1,"1\n", 2);          
                else
                {
                    sleep(2);
                    write(1,"2\n", 2);
                }

                return 0;           
            }
        }
    }       

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cpid = waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0);

        if (WTERMSIG(status))
            printf("status:%d , pid terminated:\n", status,cpid);
        else
            printf("error: not exited with a signal\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*...  one should write "2" after 2 seconds*" 2 seconds after what, please?

Comment: I'm very sorry for my poor writing in english. I meant, it waits 2 seconds and then terminate

Comment: Why do you want parent to wait for SIGCHLD? You are not catching it anyway? You can't use `WTERMSIG` without checking whether a signal was sent at first. What are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If the last for loop is changed as:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cpid = waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0);

  if (WIFEXITED(status))
        printf("status:%d , pid %d terminated normally :\n", status,cpid);
    else if (WTERMSIG(status))
        printf("status:%d , pid %d terminated by signal:\n", status,cpid);
    else
        printf("error: not exited with a signal\n");

}
```

Then the thing works better, as there is no signal to terminate the childs.